# How to add a surcharge to fine calculator in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

I am trying to create a fine amount calculator, but I don't know how to add a surcharge to the calculations.

For each fine amount in the code, I need to add a victims surcharge that varies depending on fine amount. If the fine amount is between $0 and $99 surcharge is $40, between $100 and $200 surcharge is $50, $201 and $350 surcharge is $60, $351 and $500 surcharge is $80, and over $500 surcharge is 40%.

Any suggestions for the best way to implement this into my current code?

thank you!

```
def ask_limit():
    limit = float(input ("What was the speed limit? "))
    return limit

def ask_speed():
    speed = float(input ("What was your clocked speed? "))
    return speed

def findfine(speed, limit):
    if speed > 35 + limit :
        over35fine = ((speed - limit) * 8 + 170)
        print("Total fine amount is:", over35fine)
    elif speed > 30 + limit :
        over30fine = ((speed - limit) * 4 + 100)
        print("Total fine amount is:", over30fine)
    elif speed > limit :
        normalfine = ((speed - limit) * 2 + 100)
        print("Total fine amount is:", normalfine)
    elif speed <= limit:
        print("No fine, vehicle did not exceed allowed speed limit.")


def main():
    limit = ask_limit()
    speed = ask_speed()
    findfine(speed, limit)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to do that based on the fine value:

```
def ask_limit():
    limit = float(input ("What was the speed limit? "))
    return limit

def ask_speed():
    speed = float(input ("What was your clocked speed? "))
    return speed

def findfine(speed, limit):
    if speed > 35 + limit :
        return ((speed - limit) * 8 + 170)
    elif speed > 30 + limit :
        return ((speed - limit) * 4 + 100)
    elif speed > limit :
        return ((speed - limit) * 2 + 100)
    elif speed <= limit:
        0

def findSurcharge(fine):
    if fine < 100:
        return 40
    elif fine < 200:
        return 50
    elif fine < 350:
        return 60
    elif fine < 500:
        return 80
    elif fine > 500:
        return fine * 0.4
    else:
        return 0

def main():
    limit = ask_limit()
    speed = ask_speed()
    fineAmount = findfine(speed, limit)
    surcharge = findSurcharge(fineAmount)
    print(f"fine: {fineAmount}, surcharge: {surcharge}")
main()
```

now you can print your message in the main function based on the surcharge and fine amount.

Note: adjust the if-elses in the `findSurcharge` function if they are not correct.